# execution of Spring AOP Around advice in DAO returns null in service

Tags: spring, aop

I have written my pointcut and custom around advise, which will execute one Dao method.

Pointcut

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.dao.*.get*(..))")
    public void creditPointcut(){
    }
```

Around Advice

```
@Around("creditPointcut()") 
    public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable{
        LOGGER.info("Method name: "+point.getSignature().getName()+" started");
        point.proceed();
        LOGGER.info("Method name: "+point.getSignature().getName()+" ended");

    }
```

Target - Dao Method

```
public Account getAccountDetails(int accntNo) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Account where accountNo=:acctNo");
        query.setInteger("acctNo", accntNo);
        Account account = (Account)query.list().get(0);
        return account;
    }
```

But, this advice returns null account in my service.

Service layer method

```
@Override
    @Transactional(isolation=Isolation.READ_COMMITTED )
    public Account getAccountDetails(int accntNo) {
        Account account = accountDao.getAccountDetails(accntNo);
        return account;
    }
```

Please help me why i am getting null account in my service, after executing the around advice in Dao.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

That's because you are not returning anything from the advice:

```
@Around("creditPointcut()") 
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable{
    LOGGER.info("Method name: "+point.getSignature().getName()+" started");
    Object ret = point.proceed();
    LOGGER.info("Method name: "+point.getSignature().getName()+" ended");
    return ret;

}
```

Comment: Of course, this is a PROXY around the method. Well said, thanks.